# enotez \href problem

Tags: hyperref, enotez

I'm making proof with `\href` (hyperref package) and enote (enotez package)

```
 \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[backref]{enotez}     
 \usepackage{hyperref}
 \let\footnote=\endnote

\begin{document}
     Sample text.\endnote {\href{https://www.ibm.com}} \printendnotes           
\end{document}
```

But, this code, Does not link the .pdf to the webstite

Why?

TIA

Renato

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\href has two argument. Use either \url or add the second argument. Be aware that special chars in the url (%, _ etc) can be problematic if the command is used in the argument of another (but I didn't test it).

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[backref]{enotez}
\usepackage{hyperref} \let\footnote=\endnote

\begin{document} Sample text.\endnote {\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472537/enotez-href-problem}} 

\endnote{\href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472537/enotez-href-problem}{some text}}
\printendnotes
 \end{document}
```

Comment: not even this. This, link Just to the note not to website

Comment: Works fine for me. How are you compiling? Which pdf viewer do you use?

Comment: compiler: pdflatex
viewer : sumatra pdf

Comment: ok, I've uderstand the prob:
I was thinking to clicck the number over the sentence, instead this works and I need to click the address.

ok. thatì's work!